# CanExecuteChanged event of ICommand

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, icommand

`Icommand` contains **two methods** and **one event.**

What the two methods do is clear, but **I can’t understand what the event does** that is provided in `ICommand`.

When is the `CanExecuteChanged` event raised?

The below explanation is on **MSDN** but I **can’t understand it.**

> **CanExecuteChanged** is raised if the **command manager** that
>   centralizes the commanding operations detects a change in the command
>   source that might invalidate a command that has been raised but not
>   yet executed by the command binding.

Can you please explain this in simple terms?

Thanks......

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CanExecuteChanged` is raised when the `CanExecute` method of an `ICommand` gets changed

In some 3rd party libraries, the `CanExecuteChanged` event also gets raised if the `CanExecute` parameters raise a `PropertyChanged` event. For example, MVVM Light Toolkit's `RelayCommand` raises the `CanExecuteChanged` event if the `CanExecute` parameters raise a `PropertyChanged` event, while Prism's `DelegateCommand` does not.

Comment: how does it possible to change `CanExecute` method at run time? could you please elaborate....

Comment: @Pritesh, use a predicate

Comment: @WingerSendon I see there is an alternate signature accepting a predicate of object, but don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 28):

This event is raised by the command to notify it's consumers (i.e. Button, MenuItem) that it's CanExecute property may have changed. So if focus is moved from one TextBox to another, your command may need to be enabled/disabled. This information also needs to be passed to any controls using your command.

In general, this event simply reexposes the [CommandManager.RequerySuggested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.requerysuggested.aspx) event. From the RoutedCommand class:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged {
    add {
        CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
    }
    remove {
        CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }
}
```

The RequerySuggested event is fired quite often, as focus is moved, text selection is changed. This can also be manually raised by calling [InvalidateRequerySuggested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested.aspx).

Comment: i have one delete command which delete row from datagrid, and when i move focus from datagrid to TEXTBOX it does not fire `CanExecuteChanged` as you have said...i have put two bookmark in side ADD and REMOVE block but can't getting pointer at that location...

Comment: @Pritesh - You would have to post the code you have. If the element that uses your command is not visible, then it wouldn't need to query your command. In general, you only need to fire that event when your CanExecute state changes. WPF generalized it to simply raise the event when they think the CanExecute could have changed (i.e. with focus changes, selection changes, etc).

Comment: Your answer sparks off two clarification requests: 1/ "*This event is raised by the command*": If you are writing the command from scratch and don't explicitly raise the event yourself, does it mean it will never be raised? 2/ "*In general, this event simply reexposes the CommandManager.RequerySuggested event*": Default implementation of `add` / `remove` manage subscriptions to the event, e.g. `CanExecuteChanged += value` for `add`. If you overrides them like you did, how do clients subscribe to the event in the first place?